# Want to remove white spaces from windows path

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, administrator, path

During installing Windows 10 I created my admin user as `Mubashar Javed`. It sometimes causes a problem during some software installation.

Due to this, I want to remove these whitespaces from my Windows path. I found [this answer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path) but they give a warning about serious problems.

Is there any other way to do this? And the second question is, do resetting windows settings will remove my existing Administrator and ask me for a new one?

Comment: “do resetting windows settings will remove my existing“ - Reset is basically reinstalling Windows.  However, it also depends on if you choose to keep your files

Comment: If you do not keep any data, you need a backup of all data and then you can create a new Admin account. If you keep data, that keeps your Profile and any damage or corruption in that profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not harmful, and your all settings will remain and you will continue to have Administrator privileges.

First change your username to remove the white space.

Then create a new Administrator account, log out an log in using that. Rename the user folder and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList<User SID>\ registry key and rename ProfileImagePath to the new user folder path. Then it will better to restart and log in again to your account.

Ignore their warning, they have just warned about Registry editor.

And resetting your computer is a different thing than this.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked